# Saída incorreta de dados na lista

Tags: java

Olá, o método a seguir não está mostrando corretamente a saída dos dados. No final da execução ele mostra o nome do produto e em seguida a mensagem "CPF não cadastrado". Segue uma imagem para facilitar o entendimento.

```
   public void consultarCompra(){

   System.out.println("INFORME SEU CPF: ");
    String cpf = entrada.next();

    for (int i = 0; i < dados.size(); i++) {
        if (dados.get(i).cpf.equals(cpf)) {
            System.out.println("O DONO DESTE CPF COMPROU: \n" + dados.get(i).nome);

    } else {
        System.out.println("CPF NÃO ENCONTRADO");

    }
}
```

}
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se tiver mais um item nessa lista que o CPF 123 não comprou, vai aparecer mais uma vez o "CPF NÃO ENCONTRADO". Agora pense...

Answer (score 0):

Na maneira que você programou para cada item da lista que não tenha comprado algo você imprime "CPF NÃO ENCONTRADO".
O correto para isso seria o uso de uma solução chamada de flag, que consiste em criar uma variável com um valor false, e se acontecer uma "determinada coisa" dentro do FOR, muda para true para poder usar essa informação fora do laço de repetição.

Olhe a solução:

```
public void consultarCompra(){

    boolean comprouAlgo = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < dados.size(); i++) {

        if (dados.get(i).equals(cpf)) {
            System.out.println("O DONO DESTE CPF COMPROU: \n" + dados.get(i));
            comprouAlgo = true;
        }
    }
    if (!comprouAlgo) {
        System.out.println("CPF NÃO ENCONTRADO");
    }
}
```